# how to invalidate token in Token Based Authentication OWIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

i use this code

```
public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
{
    var userIdName = context.Ticket.Identity.Name;
    long.TryParse(userIdName, out long userId);
    if (ifAndElse())
    {

        context.SetError("unauthorize");
        context.Rejected();
        return null;
    }
    var result = base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    return result;
}
```

but not destroy token and i can from postman this bear token used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution, i think is logical,
for slove this problem i use from db for keeping user login